# Dhtmlx foreachRow does not work

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I have this code, but inside foreachRow function nothing happens look:

```
SYSTEM.Grid.load(urlLoad);


 SYSTEM.Grid.forEachRow(function(id){
    console.log("teste");
}
```

Any ideas for solve this?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. You have to close the parenthesis...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function "SYSTEM.Grid.load(urlLoad);"
runing asynchronously so you need to use a callback to put the foreachRow function. That way it only after the entire grid is loaded will execute its function correctly:

```
SYSTEM.Grid.load(urlLoad, function(){
    SYSTEM.Grid.forEachRow(function(id){
        console.log("teste");
    }
});
```